# Thread stuck for ever

Tags: spring-integration, c3p0

I find this thread stuck for ever sometime in a spring integration application using c3p0 data source. Can you please advise what could be causing this, thank you

```
"lookupTaskExecutor-1" - Thread t@57   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <57d7e64f> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1108)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1173)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:381)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:342)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:190)
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcExecutor.executeStoredProcedureInternal(StoredProcExecutor.java:328)
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcExecutor.executeStoredProcedure(StoredProcExecutor.java:297)
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(StoredProcOutboundGateway.java:60)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:313)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:92)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice$2.doWithRetry(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:88)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:193)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:85)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy14.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:189)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:173)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:160)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:142)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:223)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:109)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:94)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:110)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:219)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked  (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

Comment: Looks like your connection pool is exhausted. Do you use it somewhere out side of Spring JDBC? I mean there may be some not closed connections (not returned to the pool).

Comment: Thanks Atem, i am not using the pool outside, this is happening at very high load when number of threads running are maximum. I will review how connections are being used. This task executor has just one thread and only this one is stuck, rest all the threads keep working fine utilizing the same connection pool.